# how do i read id value using java language?

Tags: android, xml-parsing

```
     {
       "id": "2345631223",
       "name": "MyFbAcc",
       "picture": "http://profile.ak.fbcdn.net/hprofile-ak-snc4  /373042_396504583708761_162084_s.jpg",
        "link": "http://www.facebook.com/MyFbAcc",
        "likes": 70,
        "cover": {
          "cover_id": 434873094856,
          "source": "http://a3.sphotos.ak.fbcdn.net/hphotos-ak-snc7/s720x720/396014_493579484001270_1795_n.jpg",
          "offset_y": 0
     }
```

Normal Xml files I used to read xml parsing/DocumentBuilderFactory, which xml consists of tags, etc, but here all are represent in " ". how do I get read the id value?

id=2345631223. Any help most welcome?

Comment: this is a JSON file, do you know the name of the object?

Answer (score 2):

Using [JSON](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidJSON/article.html)..

```
JSONObject object = new JSONObject(yourString);
String id = object.getString("id");
```

Comment: k, tahnk you. i will try u r way.

Answer (score 0):

if i suppose you are making the JSON object with a String

```
        String jString="{"name":"value"};
        JSONObject jObject = new JSONObject(jString);
```

then you can retrieve the value form the name-value pairs like

```
        String valueFromJSON= jObject.getString("name");
```